# Alternative to cp --parents in terminal

Tags: terminal, bash

I was trying to use the `--parents` option with `cp` (to create the non-existing directories in the target path) in the terminal but that option does not seem to be working in MacOS.

```
>cp --parents src_dir trgt_dir
cp: illegal option -- -
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_directory
```

Any alternative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rsync -R` (`--relative`) is like `cp --parents`. So `rsync -rR a/b c` copies to `c/a/b` instead of `c/b`.

Or just install the GNU `cp` with `brew install coreutils` or `sudo port install coreutils` and use `gcp -r --parents a/b c`.

Answer (score 1):

(Using `tree` to display directories. Installed from [homebrew](http://brew.sh/))

```
[valbaca@AppleJack foo]\$ tree
.
└── a
    └── b
        └── c
            └── d

3 directories, 1 file
[valbaca@AppleJack foo]\$ cp -R a blah
[valbaca@AppleJack foo]\$ tree
.
├── a
│   └── b
│       └── c
│           └── d
└── blah
    └── b
        └── c
            └── d
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use `mkdir -p` to create the path to the target directory first.

```
mkdir -p foo/bar/cheese
cp src_dir foo/bar/cheese
```